# Array.includes() always false, Array.indexOf() always -1 and Array.find() always undefined on Express router callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I've used `fs.readFile()` and `fs.readFileSync()` to read 'words_alpha.txt'. The file is publicly available at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt

Even though the query `test` matches a word on the `words_alpha.txt` file line array, JSON always response with `{ includes: false, indexFound: false, found: undefined, forFound: false }` with the following JavaScript code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');

router.get('/test_validation', function(req, res, next) {
  const { test } = req.query;

  fs.readFile('words_alpha.txt', function(err, data) {
    const words = data.toString().split('\n');

    const includes = words.includes(test);
    const indexFound = words.indexOf(test) > -1;
    const found = words.find(word => word === test);

    let forFound = false;
    for (i in words) {
      if (words[i] === test) {
        forFound = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    res.json({ includes, indexFound, found, forFound });
  });
});
```

Why `words.includes(test)`, `words.indexOf(test)` and `words.find(word => word === test)` couldn't found any match and even with `for (i in words) if (words[i] === test)`? But the 'words_alpha.txt' `words` can be logged one by one with `for (i in words) console.log(words[i])` but will take a few seconds to finish.

Comment: Please post the contents of `words`.

Comment: @adiga The words are logging one by one from 'a', 'aa', 'aaa' to 'zwitterionic'.

Comment: I imagine the reason you aren't finding a match in your dataset is because there is no match in your dataset. Are you sure the word exists? Is it the proper capitalisation? Does it use the correct *characters* (e.g., either diesn't contain a Cyrillic **е** as opposed to Latin **е**)? Are you sure your file has Unix line endings? If you have a file written in Windows or compatible with Windows it would have `\r\n` as line endings, not just `\n`, so splitting by the latter will leave you with "someword\r` which doesn't match "someword".

Comment: Just checked the file - it has Windows line endings, so you need to split by `\r\n`, not by `\n`. Or you can trim whitespace after splitting if you want to have this work for either kind of file. EDIT: or just convert the line endings in the file, I suppose.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, that was a crazy shit, I even wondered why the `for (i in words) console.log(\`^${words[i]}$\`)` was outputing a `^word` without `$`. `$` will only apear at the end of the loop. `.split('\r\n')` is the only solution.

Comment: Use `for (var i…`, not `for (i…` which creates a global variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the file you use has Windows style line endings (CR LF or `\r\n` expressed as characters) and you are splitting by Unix style line endings (LF or `\n`) which yields an incorrect array of words:

```js
const stringOfWords = "apple\r\nbroccoli\r\ncarrot"; //windows line endings
console.log(stringOfWords)

const words = stringOfWords.split("\n");
console.log(words);

console.log(words.includes("apple"))
```

Or you can split by Windows line endings only but you risk the code not working for Unix line endings:

```js
const stringOfWords = "apple\r\nbroccoli\r\ncarrot"; //windows line endings
console.log(stringOfWords)

const words = stringOfWords.split("\r\n");
console.log(words);

console.log(words.includes("apple"))
```

Or you can instead convert your file to Unix file endings and your code would work with no change:

```js
const stringOfWords = "apple\nbroccoli\ncarrot"; //unix line endings
console.log(stringOfWords)

const words = stringOfWords.split("\n");
console.log(words);

console.log(words.includes("apple"))
```

Or you can trim your words to remove whitespace and thus be able to handle either line endings but it could be a potentially heavy operation for large files:

```js
const stringOfWords = "apple\r\nbroccoli\r\ncarrot"; //windows line endings
console.log(stringOfWords)

const words = stringOfWords.split("\n")
  .map(word => word.trim());
console.log(words);

console.log(words.includes("apple"))
```

Or you can also split by regular expression for either Windows or Unix line endings:

```js
const stringOfWords = "apple\r\nbroccoli\r\ncarrot"; //windows line endings
console.log(stringOfWords)

const words = stringOfWords.split(/\r?\n/);
console.log(words);

console.log(words.includes("apple"))
```